# ylabel position with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am using pgfplots to plot some data, but I am having problem you see in the image below. Basically, the ylabel overlaps with the axis numbering. I have googled a LOT but couldn't find any solution. Some people say that with versions >1.2 this should be automatically fixed, but even with 1.5.1 this is still happening to me...

Is there anyway to specify the location of the ylabel? Obviously I would like it to be a bit more to the left, so it does not overlap with the numbers.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Probably the option `ylabel near ticks` for the `axis` environment will correct the position of the y-axis label.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quoting the manual, section 4.8.3 *Labels*:

> Upgrade notice: Since version 1.3, label placement can respect the
>   size of adjacent tick labels. Use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` (or newer)
>   in the preamble to activate this feature.

In the following MWE, uncomment the `pgfplotsset` line to see the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Something,scaled ticks=base 10:-11]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1000) (2,10000)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the left, with `compat=1.5`, on the right without:

[image] [image]

One could use `compat=newest` to always use the newest version, but this could lead to issues with backwards compatibility, as future versions may behave differently. (See comment from Christian Feuersänger, author of `pgfplots`, below.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however for some mysterious reason I cannot use \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}, probably I have an old version of the package that doesn't support this (and I cannot install new versions in this computer). Anyway, I found another solution, see my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan: In the question you say that you're using 1.5.1, which is the current version. `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` is definitely available. Please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in the question, and we can attempt to diagnose a conflict.

Comment: Good answer. Note, however, that the usage of `compat=newest` *has potential backwards compatibility impact*: future versions might change behavior in way that you did not anticipate. It is generally better to write `compat=1.5`.

Answer (score 18):

I am answering myself here, at the end I end up using the following style for the ylabel, which basically forces the label to appear at the coordinates that you set. I guess that this will work also with versions older than 1.3 of pgfplots.

```
  y label style={at={(-0.1,0.5)}},
```

[image]

Comment: You could rather have set `compat=1.3` inside the `axis` environment of the tikzpicture :)