# y label tikz plot interferes with y axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make an tikz plot from a matlab plot. The problem is that de y label is on the y axis.

[image: Plot image]

I used the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=320,
xlabel={$\text{Debiet [m}^\text{3}\text{/h]}$},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0, ymax=9e-006,
ylabel={$\text{d}_{\text{p,100\%}}\text{ [m]}$},
ymajorgrids,
axis lines=left,
title={ },
legend style={nodes=right}]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
coordinates{
...
addlegendentry{$\text{d}_{\text{p,100\%}}\text{ bij ideale aanstroming}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

.

I tried several things but it still doesn't work. Is there a way I can move the y label to the right or use a common scaling factor on the y-axis.

Comment: I assume you mean "move the y label to the *left*"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ylabel postion with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46634/ylabel-postion-with-pgfplots)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: It's not an exact duplicate, since this question also asks for a way to use a common scaling factor.

Comment: @Jake Sorry, you're right. I missed that last part.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a common scaling factor by supplying the option `scaled y ticks={base 10:6}`, which will multiply all y ticks with `10^6` and add the scaling factor `10^-6` to the top of the axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=320,
xlabel={$\text{Debiet [m}^\text{3}\text{/h]}$},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0, ymax=9e-006,scaled y ticks={base 10:6},
ylabel={$\text{d}_{\text{p,100\%}}\text{ [m]}$},
ymajorgrids,
axis lines=left,
title={ },
legend style={nodes=right}]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid
] coordinates {(0,7e-6) (320,3e-6)};
\addlegendentry{$\text{d}_{\text{p,100\%}}\text{ bij ideale aanstroming}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

To avoid the y axis label colliding with the tick labels, you can set the version to use to at least `compat=1.3`, which will use the special anchor `near ticklabel` for the axis labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
compat=newest,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=320,
xlabel={$\text{Debiet [m}^\text{3}\text{/h]}$},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0, ymax=9e-006,
ylabel={$\text{d}_{\text{p,100\%}}\text{ [m]}$},
ymajorgrids,
axis lines=left,
title={ },
legend style={nodes=right}]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid
] coordinates {(0,7e-6) (320,3e-6)};
\addlegendentry{$\text{d}_{\text{p,100\%}}\text{ bij ideale aanstroming}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Newer versions of `pgfplots` handle this problem automatically, but you have to call it. You can use `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` to set the compatibility globally, or use `compat=newest` within the `\begin{axis}[ ... ]` options.

This option automatically adjusts the spacing of the label to avoid the tick marks. If you want to adjust this further, use  `ylabel shift={dimension}` option (which only works when `compat=newest` is set.)

Comment: While this is correct, I would like to note that `compat=newest` means that the code in question will always and without further notice adapt changes of future versions. It is best-practice to prefer a fixed version, for example `compat=1.4` to ensure that your figure will always look the same even in future versions.

Comment: Good point. I haven't used `pgfplots` long enough to make old code obsolete, and many times the features I want exist only in the newer revisions, so I generally use `newest`. But your point is well taken.

Comment: \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} works perfectly! Thank you!