# Matlab2tikz, alignment of subplot ylabel (large distance from plot)

Tags: pgfplots, labels, matlab2tikz

Matlab2tikz came to my attention in the past month and have been using [the simple tutorial from HowToTeX](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/). It has worked great so far only one issue remains, I am unable to anchor the `ylabel` to the `yaxis`.

I use matlab to plot multiple subplots (for instance 3x3) and matlab2tikz to acquire a `.tik`z input file. I use a code similar to:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
  \scriptsize
  \centering 
  \setlength\figureheight{3cm}
  \setlength\figurewidth{3cm}
  \input{fig_matlab2tikz.tikz}
  \caption{A great subplot.} 
  \label{fig:matlabfigure} 
  \normalsize
\end{figure}
```

The `ylabel` is located too far away from the plot, so it looks like the `ylabel` belongs to a subplot to the left. I have tried to use the following code to move the labels closer but nothing changed.

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/xlabel near ticks/.style={
    /pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={
      at={(ticklabel cs:3)},anchor=near ticklabel}},
    /pgfplots/ylabel near ticks/.style={
      /pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel cs:3)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! I've tried to tidy up your code mark-up. I wonder why in the `\pgfplotsset` part you have all of those `/pgfplots/...` parts: they are not needed.

Comment: @Joseph Wright, thanks for the mark-up. I copied the code from another tex-sx question. Not that experienced with pgfplots yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will help but I had similar problem. I had solved it with putting this into document preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

[Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50318/y-label-tikz-plot-interferes-with-y-axis)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How does this solve the question? Could you elaborate a little bit on your answer?

Comment: Worked for me, and I didn't find the other question independently.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to comment on vipers36 answer, but I don't have the reputation for that.

Anyways, his answer didn't work for me directly, but after some trial and error I figured out that the following works for me:

```
\begin{axis}[
...,
ylabel style={yshift=-10pt}
]
```

or alternatively in matlab:

```
matlab2tikz(...,'extraAxisOptions','ylabel style={yshift=-10pt}');
```

Maybe this is version dependent, but for me it was crucial to add **style**, put the shift into the curly brackets and to use **yshift** instead of shift only.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Could you add full working code, starting with documentlass and \end{document}?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the y label by adding a `ylabel style` key to your axis in the .tex file:

```
\begin{axis}[
    ...,
    ylabel shift={-10pt}
]
```

You can do that directly from matlab by passing it as an `extraAxisOptions` to matlab2tikz:

```
matlab2tikz(...,'extraAxisOptions','ylabel shift={-10pt}');
```

So you don't have to modify you're .tex file each time you replot