# Is there a way to explicitly state what the ticks on a TikZ/pgfplots picture should say (ie 10.000 rather than 10)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to show that my graph has 5 significant figures on the y-axis. But I can't seem to get TikZ/pgfplots to show the trailing zeros though. I tried to get TikZ/pgfplots to show the extra zeros by using the `ytick` option, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 20,
    ymin = 10,    ymax = 10.3,
    xlabel = Concentration,
    axis x line = bottom, 
    ylabel = Mass (g),
    axis y line = left, 
    xtick = {0,5,10,15,20},
    ytick = {10.000,10.100,10.200,10.300}, % My attempt thus far
    grid = major,
    width = \textwidth - 1in,
    tick align = outside
    ]
        \addplot coordinates{
        (5,10.012)
        (10,10.180)
        (15,10.230)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's what the document currently looks like:

[image: Original]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find that when I did a Google search. But now's there's an additional problem. The y-axis label isn't far away enough from the tick labels.

Comment: The wonderful thing with TeX.SX is that nearly every question you might want to ask, has been asked (and answered) already :) The answer for your y-axis label placement problem can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46634/ylabel-postion-with-pgfplots

Comment: Again, thank you so much! The problem with this community is that finding the question isn't always easy to do. For every question I ask, I find the answer to 10 questions on Google.